NSwag generated client with custom constructor
Is it possible to use nswag an generate custom constructor with additional param. When I run nswag to generate api client, I got this ctor:
WeatherClient(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient)

how can I generate api client with this constructor:
WeatherClient(IConfiguration configuration, HttpClient httpClient, IMemoryCache memoryCache)

I know in nswag file I can set configuration class but how can I configure so I can have IMemoryCache injected in this generated client.

From the NSwag doc, NSwag uses .liquid templates for code generation, and you can customize these templates to inject additional dependencies. But there are so many templates in the NSwag templates and if you are not familiar with .Liquid format, it is hard to find the correct template and modify it. Therefore, if you don't have a lot of client files to generate, I recommend that you create a partial class to extend the generated API client. If you still want to custom template, post your question on this forum.
